# fluxbox: how to disable raise (ALT+Down/Up)

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, fluxbox

I am using fluxbox and would like to disable `Alt+Down` and `Alt+Up` when I am inside a specific application. How can I do it?

Comment: $> grep -i Down .fluxbox/keys .. aka, show us your current key-bindings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bbkeys` was overriding my key-bindings. Stopping it fixed the problem.